# LoadXml adds extra whitespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

This is how my string looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment id="123456" date="2013-05-16 11:24:59.0">
  <refund id="1" amount="10000.0" reason="refund 1"/>
  <refund id="2" amount="1200.0" reason="refund 2"/>
  <refund id="3" amount="2252.0" reason="refund 3"/>
</payment>
```

After I convert it to xml using the code below:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myString);
```

my xml document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment id="123456" date="2013-05-16 11:24:59.0">
  <refund id="1" amount="10000.0" reason="refund 1" />
  <refund id="2" amount="1200.0" reason="refund 2" />
  <refund id="3" amount="2252.0" reason="refund 3" />
</payment>
```

Notice the difference? For some reason, all "refund" elements have an extra whitespace before the closing tag. Does anybody know why it happens? I tried to set PreserveWhitespace to false but it did not help.

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your code, which makes it much harder to help you. I'd also point out that the *meaning* of the XML is the same - so you might be best just to ignore this.

Comment: I've updated my post. Not sure it would help. I agree that the meaning of the xml is the same, but I just want to figure out WHY it happens. Strangely enough it only affects "refund" elements

Comment: You still haven't shown how you're getting the output. Note that your refund elements are self-closing, unlike the payment elements.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "how you're getting the output". I'm not getting any output, this is the actual xml that's been constructed out from the string

Comment: You've got as far as an `XmlDocument` - but you've shown textual output. So you're converting the XmlDocument *back* into a string at some point. You haven't shown how you're doing this. I'm afraid I'm off to bed now, but hopefully if you can provide enough information, someone else may be able to help you...

Comment: In terms of XML, there is no difference between those two documents. Why do you care? `<a />` and `<a/>` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is because of the inline closing of the XML tag.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <payment id="123456" date="2013-05-16 11:24:59.0"**>**
      <refund id="1" amount="10000.0" reason="refund 1"**/>**
      <refund id="2" amount="1200.0" reason="refund 2"/>
      <refund id="3" amount="2252.0" reason="refund 3"/>
    </payment>
```

The payment has a seperate closing tag at the end, but the refund is a **self-closing** element. By default the a space will be added before the closing tag. If you dont want the spacing then you have to do it like the old way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <payment id="123456" date="2013-05-16 11:24:59.0">
          <refund id="1" amount="10000.0" reason="refund 1">**</refund>**
          <refund id="2" amount="1200.0" reason="refund 2"></refund>
          <refund id="3" amount="2252.0" reason="refund 3"></refund>
        </payment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `XmlDoument`  convert your XML content to it's valid markup. Meaning, there *should* be a whitespace there (it's not a must but it's the stander).

You can try and give it that entire XML in 1 row and I Friday the result will be the same as here..